# Horizontal to vertical table

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have this query

```
SELECT quiz_id, COUNT(case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"1%' then 1 else null end) as 'answered 1',
COUNT(case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"2%' then 1 else null end) as 'answered 2',
COUNT(case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"3%' then 1 else null end) as 'answered 3',
COUNT(case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"4%' then 1 else null end) as 'answered 4',
COUNT(case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"5%' then 1 else null end) as 'answered 5',
COUNT(case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"6%' then 1 else null end) as 'answered 6',
COUNT(case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"7%' then 1 else null end) as 'answered 7',
COUNT(case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"8%' then 1 else null end) as 'answered 8'
FROM wp_aysquiz_reports
WHERE quiz_id = 2;
```

and I have this result

[image: I have this as a result]

How can I make it like this:

```
Answered 1    7
Answered 2    3
Answered 3    1
Answered 4    1
Answered 5    1
Answered 6    1
Answered 7    1
Answered 8    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done in the original query is considered pivoting, you could either apply an unpivot afterwards or just not do the pivoting.

The special thing about your data seems like `options` could potentially have multiple matching `like` conditions, so you could `union all` each version and aggregate that:

```
select quiz_id, question, count(*) 
from (
          SELECT quiz_id, case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"1%' then 'answered 1' else null end as question FROM wp_aysquiz_reports where quiz_id = 2
union all SELECT quiz_id, case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"2%' then 'answered 2' else null end as question FROM wp_aysquiz_reports where quiz_id = 2
union all SELECT quiz_id, case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"3%' then 'answered 3' else null end as question FROM wp_aysquiz_reports where quiz_id = 2
union all SELECT quiz_id, case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"4%' then 'answered 4' else null end as question FROM wp_aysquiz_reports where quiz_id = 2
union all SELECT quiz_id, case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"5%' then 'answered 5' else null end as question FROM wp_aysquiz_reports where quiz_id = 2
union all SELECT quiz_id, case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"6%' then 'answered 6' else null end as question FROM wp_aysquiz_reports where quiz_id = 2
union all SELECT quiz_id, case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"7%' then 'answered 7' else null end as question FROM wp_aysquiz_reports where quiz_id = 2
union all SELECT quiz_id, case when options LIKE '%question_id_8":"8%' then 'answered 8' else null end as question FROM wp_aysquiz_reports where quiz_id = 2
)
where question is not null
group by quiz_id,question
```

Note I've included a *group by* condition, this is because you want a row per `quiz_id, question` and you don't just want MySQL to give you an arbitrary value (see [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)).

Instead of using a `case when` expression in each of the selects, you could just use a filter `where options LIKE '%question_id_8":"1%'` etc. This could be faster, you would also not require the `where question is not null` filter at the end. I preferred rewriting as I did because it's easier to follow from your original statement.